# Modify and combine two different frozen graphs generated using tensorflow object detection API for inference

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am working with TensorFlow object detection API, I have trained two different(SSD-mobilenet and FRCNN-inception-v2) models for my use case. Currently, my workflow is like this:

1. Take an input image, detect one particular object using SSD
   mobilenet.
2. Crop the input image with the bounding box generated from
   step 1 and then resize it to a fixed size(e.g. 200 X 300).
3. Feed this cropped and resized image to FRCNN-inception-V2 for detecting
   smaller objects inside the ROI.

Currently at the time of inferencing, when I load two separate frozen graphs and follow the steps, I am getting my desired results. But I need only a single frozen graph because of my deployment requirement. I am new to TensorFlow and wanted to combine both graphs with crop and resizing process in between them.

Comment: Have you tried creating a custom layer? https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers

Comment: @matt Yes for cropping and resizing, I can use crop_and_resize method and it can be added as custom layer. Did you mean, I should modify the model architecture before training? Because after training, I have checkpoint files, with which I am trying to recreate a graph and add custom layers and finally combine both models. But I am not sure about the way.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can build a new model that has uses your previous models, and a custom layer. Not before training, but using the trained models and a custom layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks, @matt and @Vedanshu for responding, Here is the updated code that works fine for my requirement, Please give suggestions, if it needs any improvement as I am still learning it.

```
# Dependencies
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


# load graphs using pb file path
def load_graph(pb_file):
    graph = tf.Graph()
    with graph.as_default():
        od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        with tf.gfile.GFile(pb_file, 'rb') as fid:
            serialized_graph = fid.read()
            od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
            tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='') 
    return graph


# returns tensor dictionaries from graph
def get_inference(graph, count=0):
    with graph.as_default():
        ops = tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
        all_tensor_names = {output.name for op in ops for output in op.outputs}
        tensor_dict = {}
        for key in ['num_detections', 'detection_boxes', 'detection_scores',
                    'detection_classes', 'detection_masks', 'image_tensor']:
            tensor_name = key + ':0' if count == 0 else '_{}:0'.format(count)
            if tensor_name in all_tensor_names:
                tensor_dict[key] = tf.get_default_graph().\
                                        get_tensor_by_name(tensor_name)
        return tensor_dict


# renames while_context because there is one while function for every graph
# open issue at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22162  
def rename_frame_name(graphdef, suffix):
    for n in graphdef.node:
        if "while" in n.name:
            if "frame_name" in n.attr:
                n.attr["frame_name"].s = str(n.attr["frame_name"]).replace("while_context",
                                                                           "while_context" + suffix).encode('utf-8')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # your pb file paths
    frozenGraphPath1 = '...replace_with_your_path/some_frozen_graph.pb'
    frozenGraphPath2 = '...replace_with_your_path/some_frozen_graph.pb'

    # new file name to save combined model
    combinedFrozenGraph = 'combined_frozen_inference_graph.pb'

    # loads both graphs
    graph1 = load_graph(frozenGraphPath1)
    graph2 = load_graph(frozenGraphPath2)

    # get tensor names from first graph
    tensor_dict1 = get_inference(graph1)

    with graph1.as_default():

        # getting tensors to add crop and resize step
        image_tensor = tensor_dict1['image_tensor']
        scores = tensor_dict1['detection_scores'][0]
        num_detections = tf.cast(tensor_dict1['num_detections'][0], tf.int32)
        detection_boxes = tensor_dict1['detection_boxes'][0]

        # I had to add NMS becuase my ssd model outputs 100 detections and hence it runs out of memory becuase of huge tensor shape
        selected_indices = tf.image.non_max_suppression(detection_boxes, scores, 5, iou_threshold=0.5)
        selected_boxes = tf.gather(detection_boxes, selected_indices)

        # intermediate crop and resize step, which will be input for second model(FRCNN)
        cropped_img = tf.image.crop_and_resize(image_tensor,
                                               selected_boxes,
                                               tf.zeros(tf.shape(selected_indices), dtype=tf.int32),
                                               [300, 60] # resize to 300 X 60
                                               )
        cropped_img = tf.cast(cropped_img, tf.uint8, name='cropped_img')


    gdef1 = graph1.as_graph_def()
    gdef2 = graph2.as_graph_def()

    g1name = "graph1"
    g2name = "graph2"

    # renaming while_context in both graphs
    rename_frame_name(gdef1, g1name)
    rename_frame_name(gdef2, g2name)

    # This combines both models and save it as one
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as g_combined:

        x, y = tf.import_graph_def(gdef1, return_elements=['image_tensor:0', 'cropped_img:0'])

        z, = tf.import_graph_def(gdef2, input_map={"image_tensor:0": y}, return_elements=['detection_boxes:0'])

        tf.train.write_graph(g_combined, "./", combinedFrozenGraph, as_text=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load output of one graph into another using `input_map` in `import_graph_def`. Also you have to rename the `while_context` because there is one `while` function for every graph. Something like this:

```
def get_frozen_graph(graph_file):
    """Read Frozen Graph file from disk."""
    with tf.gfile.GFile(graph_file, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    return graph_def

def rename_frame_name(graphdef, suffix):
    # Bug reported at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22162#issuecomment-428091121
    for n in graphdef.node:
        if "while" in n.name:
            if "frame_name" in n.attr:
                n.attr["frame_name"].s = str(n.attr["frame_name"]).replace("while_context",
                                                                           "while_context" + suffix).encode('utf-8')
...

l1_graph = tf.Graph()
with l1_graph.as_default():
    trt_graph1 = get_frozen_graph(pb_fname1)
    [tf_input1, tf_scores1, tf_boxes1, tf_classes1, tf_num_detections1] = tf.import_graph_def(trt_graph1, 
            return_elements=['image_tensor:0', 'detection_scores:0', 'detection_boxes:0', 'detection_classes:0','num_detections:0'])

    input1 = tf.identity(tf_input1, name="l1_input")
    boxes1 = tf.identity(tf_boxes1[0], name="l1_boxes")  # index by 0 to remove batch dimension
    scores1 = tf.identity(tf_scores1[0], name="l1_scores")
    classes1 = tf.identity(tf_classes1[0], name="l1_classes")
    num_detections1 = tf.identity(tf.dtypes.cast(tf_num_detections1[0], tf.int32), name="l1_num_detections")

...
# Make your output tensor 
tf_out = # your output tensor (here, crop the input image with the bounding box generated from step 1 and then resize it to a fixed size(e.g. 200 X 300).)
...

connected_graph = tf.Graph()

with connected_graph.as_default():
    l1_graph_def = l1_graph.as_graph_def()
    g1name = 'ved'
    rename_frame_name(l1_graph_def, g1name)
    tf.import_graph_def(l1_graph_def, name=g1name)

    ...

    trt_graph2 = get_frozen_graph(pb_fname2)
    g2name = 'level2'
    rename_frame_name(trt_graph2, g2name)
    [tf_scores, tf_boxes, tf_classes, tf_num_detections] = tf.import_graph_def(trt_graph2,
            input_map={'image_tensor': tf_out},
            return_elements=['detection_scores:0', 'detection_boxes:0', 'detection_classes:0','num_detections:0'])


#######
# Export the graph

with connected_graph.as_default():
    print('\nSaving...')
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    path = os.path.join(cwd, 'saved_model')
    shutil.rmtree(path, ignore_errors=True)
    inputs_dict = {
        "image_tensor": tf_input
    }
    outputs_dict = {
        "detection_boxes_l1": tf_boxes_l1,
        "detection_scores_l1": tf_scores_l1,
        "detection_classes_l1": tf_classes_l1,
        "max_num_detection": tf_max_num_detection,
        "detection_boxes_l2": tf_boxes_l2,
        "detection_scores_l2": tf_scores_l2,
        "detection_classes_l2": tf_classes_l2
    }
    tf.saved_model.simple_save(
        tf_sess_main, path, inputs_dict, outputs_dict
    )
    print('Ok')
```

Comment: Thanks, @Vedanshu, Yes you are right, I need to rename the while_context because there is one while function for every graph. I also came across this error and I found this link which pretty much does the same thing which you have explained above: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22162
Thanks for sharing the answer and I would also update my final script here after combining all steps and few testings.